# OnClick through mapping not hitting the parent level

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to get onClick to work in React through a mapping. When I do a console.log() on the parent level and child level, I only see me hitting the child level. Is my onclick at the parent level incorrect?

Parent Level

```
export default ({}) => (
   <div>
       {channels.map(c => (
          <Channels
             onClick={async () => {
                console.log('Parent');
             }}
          />
       ))}
   </div>
)
```

Child Level

```
class Channels extends React.Component {
    onClick() {
        console.log('Child');
    }

    render () {
        return (
           <Link onClick={this.onclick()} to={...}>
              <NewMessage># {channel.name}</NewMessage>
           </Link>
        );
    }
}
```

Why does Parent not print out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on your parent Level you are passing a prop `onClick` to `Channels` component. but you never called that on `Channels` component.

if you want to call the `onClick` passed from Parent level to `Channels` then your component should be like following:

```
class Channels extends React.Component {
    render () {
        return (
           <Link onClick={this.props.onClick} to={...}>
              <NewMessage># {channel.name}</NewMessage>
           </Link>
        );
    }
}
```

Now it should call Parent level `onClick`.

if you want to call the `onClick` defined in `Channels` component then your component should be like following:

```
class Channels extends React.Component {
    onClick() {
        console.log('Child');
    }

    render () {
        return (
           <Link onClick={this.onClick} to={...}>
              <NewMessage># {channel.name}</NewMessage>
           </Link>
        );
    }
}
```

notice you had `onClick={this.onclick()}` i changed it to `onClick={this.onClick}` because Javascript is case sensitive language and also removed the parenthesis as thats not the correct way to attach handler.

and if you want to call both `onClick` of child and parent both then the component should be like following:

```
class Channels extends React.Component {
    onClick(event) {
        this.props.onClick(event);
        console.log('Child');
    }

    render () {
        return (
           <Link onClick={this.onClick} to={...}>
              <NewMessage># {channel.name}</NewMessage>
           </Link>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The parent's `onClick` can be access from the props via `this.props.onClick` in the child. Also you want to reference the function, and not the result of the function in the `<Link >` component. That looks like: `onClick={this.onclick}` instead of `onClick={this.onclick()}`

The parent isn't printing because it is not being reference in the child component. The child component is creating it's on `onClick` that is used via `this.onClick` whereas the parent's on click is in `this.props.onClick`

```
class Channels extends React.Component {
  onClick() {
    const { onClick } = this.props
    onClick() // parent
    console.log('Child');
  }

  render () {
    return (
       <Link onClick={this.onclick} to={...}>
          <NewMessage># {channel.name}</NewMessage>
       </Link>
    );
  }
}
```